# Dynamically changing ImageButton PostBackURL property

Tags: imagebutton, postbackurl

I am using `ASP.NET 2.0`.  I am building a table with an `ImageButton` in each cell.

If the user clicks on a `dropdown`, I do a postback and rebuild the table with a new set of ImageButtons.

When the user clicks on an ImageButton, I show the `PostBackURL` property in a Javascript confirm box, and it is correct.

However, when I proceed after the postback described above, the actual `PostBackURL` is the one from that cell **before** the page did the postback.

I am building each `ImageButton` with a unique `ID` on each page.

Does anyone have any ideas why the `PostBackURL` shown on the ImageButton click is not actually being used?

Comment: If I look at the page source, after the postback, I see the updated text in the Javascript confirm code, but the PostBackURL for the ImageButton is not changed from the initial page load, despite the control having a new, unique ID.

Comment: I believe I have resolved this by setting EnableViewState=False on the Table.  But, I'm not sure why the PostBackURL property was retained when the control's ID was changed.  So, if anyone can help answer this, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a query string to capture the image buttons id.. Depending on the query string, the  required image is displayed inside the image button

eg: `response.redirect("home.aspx?imgid"+ib.id);`

in the home page: `string a=request.querystring("imgid");`

Comment: I do build a query string in the PostBackURL with the imageID, but the prior query string value (as part of the postbackURL) was sent when the image is clicked when viewstate was enabled

Answer (score 0):

and?..or else just do this.

image button has a post back url r8 so when the user clicks on an image capture its id using jquery [$('#imagebutton').attr('id')] and just save this info in a hidden field and retreive the value using request.form["hiddenfield"]..

Answer (score 0):

Just check the spelling used. It should be **Url** instead of **URL**. So, try using `PostBackUrl` instead of `PostBackURL`.